# Python try/except statement for socket error Errno 10060

Tags: python, urlopen, try-except

I have a Python 2.7 script that consists of opening/scraping multiple URLs from a database and extracting some information out of the webpages. The code can take up to 8 hours to run and I am dealing with multiple websites.

Every now and then (1-2 hours), I randomly get the error message `IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060]` while trying to open a URL

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060] A connection attempt
failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
period of time, or established connection failed because connected
host has failed to respond
```

I tried to avoid the error by adding a 2 sec pause with `time.sleep(2)` between the URL opening operations but I still get the error. The error seems to be independent of the website from which I am trying to open the URL.

I was looking at a way to prevent my script from crashing using a try/except statement.
In the event of a socket error, the script would pause for something like 20 sec and then, retry to open the URL. If the URL opens correctly, move on with the script. I'm using `urlopen()` to open the URLs.

Comment: It would be convenient if you could show your code.

Comment: It would be even more convenient if you showed us the specific part of the code that throws the exception.

Comment: and if possible show the stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code raises an `IOError`, run this code, but substitute your line of error for the `raise`.

```
try:
    raise IOError
except IOError:
    time.sleep(20)
    pass
else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is so rare and only happens every hour or so, you can probably blame your internet connection. The code you are looking for is:

```
import time
for url in urls:
    while True:
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            #Do stuff
        except :
            time.sleep(20)
        else :
            #stops the inner loop if there is no error
            break
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I put the commands that have to be executed once I open the URL after `response = urllib2.urlopen(url)` or after the last `break` line. What would be more efficient and readable? I have approximately 20 lines of code to executed after the URL opening part

Comment: I would do it inside the else block, but it depends if you expect any Exceptions in there. I think try blocks should contain as little code as possible. If you want to handle exceptions raised by the follow up code, I would put it inside another try block .